# Need of Global variable in php

Tags: php, global-variables

I need to know how to declare a global variable that has the scope in all php file.
After form submit the `$_POST` or `$_GET` arrays are reinitialised to zero. I dont want that to happen.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Normally a so called shared-nothing approach is a helpful mental device.

Answer (score 4):

Each time you load a page in PHP, it is a separate program execution, so global variables can't be maintained across multiple page loads and submits.

What you're looking for is PHP's Sessions, which are kept in the `$_SESSION` variable. These do persist across multiple page loads, which is what you're looking for.

You need to start each page with the `session_start()` function, after which you can use `$_SESSION` variables. Anything you write to `$_SESSION` will still be there in subsequent page loads (provided you've called `session_start()` each time).

I suggest you research sessions in PHP in the PHP manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php